# Chat client application isn't reciving and sending any data

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I got basic client-server chat application. Server side seems to work, when I connect with it via telnet, it receives the message and sends it back to all connected clients. I can't achieve the same using my own client tho.

So from the beginning, `Server` class

```
public class Server  {
    private Properties properties;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Set<ClientConnection> clientConnections;   

    public Server() throws IOException {
        clientConnections = new HashSet<>();

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
        while(true){
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection(clientSocket, this);
            clientConnections.add(clientConnection);
            clientConnection.start();
        }
    }

    public Set<ClientConnection> getClientConnections() {
        return clientConnections;
    }
}
```

On every connection is new `ClientConnection` created that at the beginning, sends "Hello from server" to new client (working if connects via telnet) and then, listens for all incoming messages and broadcast them to all connected clients, again - working if telnet is a client.

```
public class ClientConnection extends Thread {
    private final Socket clientSocket;
    private final Server server;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private InputStream inputStream;    

    public ClientConnection(Socket clientSocket, Server server) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            handleClient();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleClient() throws IOException {
        outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        outputStream.write("Hello from server".getBytes());
        System.out.println("New client connected");         

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String incomingMessage;

        while((incomingMessage = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            for(ClientConnection connection : server.getClientConnections()) {
                connection.getOutputStream().write(incomingMessage.getBytes());
            }
            System.out.println(incomingMessage);
        }
        clientSocket.close();
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return outputStream;
    }
}
```

And then, I got Client application with `ServerConnection` class

```
    public class ServerConnection{
        private Socket socket;
        private OutputStream outputStream;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        private String host;
        private int port;

        public ServerConnection(String host, int port) {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
        }

        public void connect() throws IOException {


        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        outputStream.write("Hello from client".getBytes());

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String incommingMessage;

            while((incommingMessage = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(incommingMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

And it actually is registered by the server side (prints "New client connected"), but it isn't receiving "Hello from client" and the client isn't receiving any messages from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to send new lines at the end of your message from client, i.e.: `outputStream.write("Hello from client\r\n\".getBytes());`, as you are using `bufferedReader.readLine()` in your sever code. So BufferedReader is waiting for line end and nothing is happening.

Comment: Would never came up with idea that simple, new line did the job.

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the code for you, as you have what you need. But here is a flow, that took me a while myself to fully understand, which should help you out.

Server:

```
Start -> Accept connection -> Read InStream -> Write OutStream (FLUSH THE TOILET OF DATA) -> Loop
```

Client:

```
Start -> Connect -> Write OutStream (FLUSH THE TOILET OF DATA) -> Read InStream -> Close Connection
```